# Get specific key and the rest of map with Pattern Matching in Elixir

Tags: dictionary, pattern-matching, elixir

Im trying to get one element and the rest of the map with pattern matching but I'm only get compile errors.

I came up with this:

```
%{“One” => one | tail} = %{“One" => 1, "Three" => 3, "Two" => 2}
```

But I got compile errors saying that it was expected key-value pairs.

The behavior that I'm trying to achieve is:

```
%{“One” => one | tail} = %{“One" => 1, "Three" => 3, "Two" => 2}
one = 1
tail = %{"Three" => 3, "Two" => 2}
```

In elixir there is a way to acomplished that?

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't a syntax for this but if you want to remove only one key, you can use `Map.pop/3`: `Map.pop(%{a: 1, b: 2}, :a) #=> {1, %{b: 2}}`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax for this in Elixir as of version 1.6 but if you want to only remove one value from the map at once, you can use `Map.pop/2`:

```
iex(1)> {one, tail} = Map.pop(%{"One" => 1, "Three" => 3, "Two" => 2}, "One")
{1, %{"Three" => 3, "Two" => 2}}
iex(2)> one
1
iex(3)> tail
%{"Three" => 3, "Two" => 2}
```